# how to change the default form input size in yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, yii2, gii

i have creted  a form by gii CRUD application.  but the form has very wide input fields i don't want that much wide input fields. how can i do that. Any suggestion are highly welcome.my form code is.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'group_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'group_num')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'num_member')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'monthly_prm')->textInput() ?>


<?= $form->field($model, 'chit_sdate')->textInput(['placeholder'=> "dd-mm-yy"]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'chit_cdate')->textInput(['placeholder'=> "dd-mm-yy"]) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: use some designing like row and column.

Comment: i particularly want to know what attributes should i add  in                         <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([what to set herreeee]); ?>

Comment: Refer [ActiveForm()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html) for possible options.

Comment: @InsaneSkull thanks for your suggestion and quick support

Answer (score 0):

got my answer... :)
just add these in  when your active form begins add do changes accordingly

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'login-form',
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'template' => "{label}\n<div class=\"col-lg-3\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
            'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1 control-label'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```